# how to call user defined function in web api using ajax methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I am facing problem to call user defined web api function in MVC4 Please suggest how can i do this. i am first time using web api.

My API Function :

```
     public List<Voice> GetVoicesByStatus(string Status)
    {
        List<Voice> Voc = db.Voices.Where(x => x.Status == Status).ToList();
        if (Status == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return Voc;
    }
```

Ajax Method :

```
       function GetVoicesByStatus(status) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/api/Applications/VoicesByStatus/' + status,
            data: JSON.stringify({}),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'AuthToken': '2FEA7374-EBA2-4367-9492-6DB3334AD2AF' },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var str = "<tr><td>" + data[i].ID + "</td><td>" + data[i].APIKey + "</td><td>" + data[i].CreatedBy + "</td><td><a href='#' onclick='fnDelete(&#39;" + data[i].ID + "&#39;)'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
                    $("#app").append(str);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Error :

[image]

Comment: Seems it's a CORS issue. You try to call a different address than your own application?

Comment: It is working with other HTTP Verb like GET, PUT, POST and DELETE but when i am calling my own function is showing error and by the way how can i call it in ajax method

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx.xx:xx/api/Applications/GetVoicesByStatus?status=' + status,
            contentType: 'application/json',T                
            headers: { 'AuthToken': '2FEA7374-EBA2-4367-9492-6DB3334AD2AF' },
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var str = "<tr><td>" + data[i].ID + "</td><td>" + data[i].APIKey + "</td><td>" + data[i].CreatedBy + "</td><td><a href='#' onclick='fnDelete(&#39;" + data[i].ID + "&#39;)'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
                    $("#app").append(str);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is CORS related issue. In MVC4 there is no default CORS handler. And use JSONP for as data-type. For enabling CORS please refer below link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx

It may helps you.